# xCode Localization - where to put .lproj files?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I've looked for similar questions, but this must have been asked before. Either way, please point me in the right direction.

I've localized an app for the first time. It seems to work ok, but I have two sets of .lproj files. One set is in the settings bundle, and the other is in the main project directory.

It also appears that some settings are affected by one .lproj file content and other settings are affected by the other.

Should I leave "well enough" alone? Should I combine somehow? If so, where is the correct place?

If I find this has already been answered, please forgive. I will either delete this question, or point it to the existing response.

Thanks

Comment: My lproj's are scattered in the project folder.

Comment: cool. thanks!  Do you have a settings bundle? And if so, do you have lproj files in there too?

Comment: Yes, actually.  If you'd seen the actual finder window with my project, it's a mess!  Thank goodness for the Xcode file tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really OK to have lproj's all over the project. What is more important - to keep translated files inside of Xcode file tree. You can easily localize your nibs and any other files just by selecting file you need to localize and by adding File localization in File Inspector.

Comment: Thanks a ton Maxim. Could you or CodaFi elaborate on what is supposed to be in these directories? I have Localization.strings, Root.strings...

Comment: Usually there are Localizable.strings and localized versions of your nib-files in this directories. But there can be any type of files, e.g. I have different .html and .png files for different languages in one of my projects.